# AWS Lambda not showing code to edit in line

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I want to edit my code inline on AWS Lambda, which I was able to do until I uploaded a zip file. Now the editor has disappeared and I can't bring it back to edit the code I uploaded. I think there is a simple fix for this but can't seem to find it. How can I bring my editor back? I couldn't find anything on the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/code-editor.html).
[image]

Answer (score 1):

When your project is big enough, the inline editor will not be shown anymore

Comment: How big is too big?

Comment: Is that still true, now that the new IDE has been integrated?

Comment: I just have the initial lambda and dont see anything

Comment: It seems that golang runtime contains only the binary not the actual code... thats why its too big and there is no code ... what the hell? why dont you compile the code? How I know if im building on the correct platform?

Answer (score 1):

You can try double clicking on the python file in the aws lambda page. Worked for me